# Question about symmetric matrix with $A=QRQ^{-1}$ with $R$ upper triangular and $Q$ orthogonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, symmetric-matrices

Suppose:
$A$ is symmetric with $A = QRQ^{-1}$. 
$Q$ is an orthogonal matrix
$R$ is an upper triangular matrix.

Prove that $R$ must be a diagonal matrix.

I tried using the fact that every symmetric matrix $A$ is orthogonal diagonalizable. 
So $A = QDQ^{-1}$ and $A = QRQ^{-1}$ so $D = R$. However then I assume that $Q$ in both diagonalizations are the same which does not always have to be the case right? So how do I prove this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Transpose both sides in the equation $A = QRQ^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Easy prove but could just not come up with the right way to think about it.

Comment: @JustvanderVeeken We're told that $A$ is symmetric, and that $Q$ is orthogonal, which means that $Q^{-1} = Q^T$. That hints that the first thing to try is just to transpose everything and see what comes out on the other end. This time we were lucky and it actually leads to a solution.